# Github Visual Studio plugin: Only Enterprise is available for login

Tags: c#, .net, github

I had to switch from Github to Team Foundation Server and now back to Github, at the login screen I see two 'options', one just 'GitHub' and 'GitHub Enterprise'.

For some reason only Enterprise is active and free GitHub is not selectable.

How do I select the free login?

Comment: Do you happen to have already a connection? If you're completely unconnected, there would be a 'Connect' link directly under 'GitHub' in TeamExplorer.
Otherwise it reads just: 'Clone | Create | Sign out' which is a hinz, you're already somehow connected.

Comment: This is a pretty old question, I probably did it some other way. Thanks for taking the time to respond though!

Comment: Yup, sorry I realized the age of the question just later. But then I thought, well, maybe it's just a hint for other readers and left it there.